# How do I change the wallpaper through the command line?

Tags: desktop, command-line, pantheon, wallpaper

Is there any DConf/Gsettings etc. interface for changing the wallpaper through the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the [Set Wallpaper Contract](https://code.launchpad.net/~donadigo/switchboard-plug-pantheon-shell/set-wallpaper-contract-1191929) there already is a convenient way to set a new wallpaper: `set-wallpaper`

Example:

```
set-wallpaper ~/Downloads/coolpicture.png
```

---

`set-wallpaper some-name.png` will set as wallpaper the file `~/some-name.png`.

If there is no such file at that location, it will create a black desktop: for example a command like `set-wallpaper x`.

Comment: That has to be just typed into the Terminal? Awesome.

Comment: [Panthon Files context menu entry to set image as wallpaper](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/10894/170)

Comment: does it take arguments - like centered, scaled, stretched etc?

Comment: In Hera the command is `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/io.elementary.contract.set-wallpaper ~/some-name.png`.