# Panthon Files context menu entry to set image as wallpaper

Tags: pantheon-files, files, wallpaper, contract

I know how to edit a contract file, but what command should be used with that?

Comment: In Loki, at least, there is already the option "Set As Desktop Background" in the context menu that does this. Works with jpg and png files anyway.

Comment: You can find the corresponding contract in /usr/share/contractor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact in Loki it's already there. As indicated in the comment below the question.

> You can find the corresponding contract in /usr/share/contractor